# Access variable from config.groovy( in conf directory) inside a quartz job

Tags: grails, groovy, config, quartz-scheduler

I have a hashmap in config.groovy which i want to access from a Quartz Job in groovy

```
Map<String,Map<String, String>> projectname.config.Map1 = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

which i want to access inside the Quartz Job below:

```
import projectname.grails-app.conf.*;

class TrialJob {

    static triggers = {            
        simple repeatInterval: 10000l // execute job once in 5 seconds          
    }

    def execute() {

        def Application

        Map<String,Map<String, String>> Holder = Application.projectname.config.Map1
        log.info()        
    }
}
```

Comment: Dependency injection makes no sense for method variables like that - they need to be fields or methods so they're visible outside of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare the map in `Config.groovy` with

```
projectname.config.Map1 = []
```

(presumably you'll also want to put something in the map), then you should be able to retrieve it from your job class as shown below

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication

class TrialJob {
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    static triggers = {            
        simple repeatInterval: 10000l // execute job once in 5 seconds          
    }

    def execute() {
        Map<String,Map<String, String>> map = grailsApplication.config.projectname.config.Map1     
    }
}
```

Comment: gives me unable to resolve class GrailsApplication while running grails run-app

Comment: you need to import it (see above)

Comment: Hi Dónal..it does'nt give the compilation error now so i assume it can access it, but when i try to print some other string variable String str ="XYZ" in config.groovy and try to print it inside execute() method in Quartz job by using log.info(grailsApplication.config.projectname.str) it does not print anything ? i tried assigning it to variable and print ,that does not print as well ...